# TypeError: type.__new__() argument 2 must be tuple, not str

Tags: python-3.x, string, tuples, typeerror

I get the following error when I run the piece of code below. I can clearly print the value of `*strs` on screen, which appears as string. But, when I do `type(*strs)`, it throws `TypeError: type.__new__() argument 2 must be tuple, not str`. Can someone explain this behaviour?

```
strs = ["flower","flood","flight"]
print(*strs)
print(type(strs))
print(type(*strs))
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
print(type(*strs))
TypeError: type.__new__() argument 2 must be tuple, not str
flower flood flight
<class 'list'>
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the star operator mean, in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-a-function-call)

Comment: Please add a plain python tag

Comment: His question was a little more involved than that. Specifically, he wanted an explanation as to the meaning of "type.__new__() argument 2 must be tuple, not str", and why his code caused that specific error. He wasn't asking what the star means.

Answer (score 3):

The asterix operator in '*strs' unpacks the iterms in 'strs', which is a series of three strings. Your code ran into trouble when it tried to send those strings to the type() command, where type() was initialized by its __ new__() magic method.

type() has two forms:

1.) type(object) where the 'object' is an instance of some class.

2.) type(name, bases, dictionary) where 'bases' is a tuple that itemizes base classes, and a dictionary that contains definitions of base classes.

In your code, the use of the unpacking operation, *strs, resulted in type() being sent three arguments, so it was expecting a name, a tuple, and a dictionary. What it, and then __ new()__ got was three strings: A name (it received 'flower'), then another string, "flood", where it wanted a tuple. Here python threw the error and never made it to the third string, 'flight'.

We can duplicate the error with:

```
 print(type("a","b","c"))
```

We can also see that either one or three (but not two) arguments were expected, with:

```
 print(type("a","b"))
```

while the following command works just fine:

```
print(type("a"))
```

If you want to see the type of each member of *strs, first let it unpack to a list, then iterate through that list, printing the type of each member as you go.

```
 mylist = [*strs]
 for elm in mylist:
      print(type(elm))
```

Does this answer the question of what caused that behavior and the error?